# Execute command on remote server and execute next command without waiting for 1st to finish

Tags: ssh, nohup

I am not from a Unix background.

I have a query to perform on Unix to execute on remote server.

Requirements -
We have 11 Unix servers and I want to stop running the application on those servers without waiting for the query to finish on the 1st server, and the next query should run or start the same command at the same time on all servers at once.

Example:

```
//test.sh
ssh host1 'command' 
ssh host2 'command'
```

Can anyone tell me how can I execute respective commands in script?

Comment: ssh host1 'command' & ssh host2 'command' should run the commands simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Use the [parallel command](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

```
parallel --onall -S ${host1},{host2} test.sh ::: command
```

Comment: Dear etr, respective command will be very helpful. I am sorry but I am very naive in unix shell scripting. I tried above command  parallel --onall -S ${host1},${host2} ls  = returned as "Missing }." and when I try parallel --onall -S $host1,$host2 ls  = returned as 'Undefined variable' , i guess respective command should have SSH in between to connect other server.  Kindly suggest.